# VBO hook_entity_update

Tags: 8, views, emails, entities

I would like to perform the following mass action via VBO: send a mail to author of a node.

This mail is configured and sent in a hook_entity_update function.

The beginning of the function is the following :

```
if (is_null($entity)) return;
if (!isset($entity)) return;

$nid = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('node');
if ($nid) {
 $type = $node->bundle();
 if ($type != 'membre') {
   return;
 }
}
else if ($nid == null) {
 return;
}

...

$mailManager->mail($module, $key, $to_trsf, $langcode, $params, NULL, $send);
```

test 1: If I update manually the node, the mail is sent.

test 2: If I update the node through a VBO, the mail is not sent because the nid is null, so the "return" statement is done.

Is there a possibility to retrieve the nid of a node when the hook is fired throught a VBO action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using `routeMatch()` to get the node id, which won't be returned when using VBO.

You said you're using `hook_entity_update()`:

```
function hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity)
```

This code assumes that the entity you are running `hook_entity_update()` for is the node entity.

Since the hook provides the `$entity` object, you can get the node id like this:

`$nid = $entity->id()`

Comment: Thank you for the solution!

Comment: You're welcome.  If the solution solves your problem, please click the checkbox to mark this answer as accepted.  On this site, if you mark the question as accepted, you don't have to say thanks :)

Comment: Yes, hooks should never presuppose they are only invoked from a specific page and retrieve values they need from the URL. The code of every route could save an entity, which means `hook_entity_update()` could be invoked from any route.